# Wallet RPC transaction notification

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I am trying to use the `--tx-notify` feature of monero-wallet-rpc with curl.

```
--tx-notify 'curl http:xxxxxx/sample/%s'
```

But this isn't triggering my function at `http:xxxxx/sample/%s`.

Is there something wrong with my argument code?

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you are using for the URL this is difficult to answer. For example `http:xxxxx` is missing `//` after `:`. Also, does calling your URL manually work? E.g. can you call `curl http://xxxxxx/sample/asdf`?

Answer (score 1):

Is seems to be a bug: monero-wallet-rpc should have printed an error message in RED telling you that it could not find curl, because you did not give the path to it. Surely, since you would have obviously read such an error message if one had been present, it must have been missing.